# How can i controll the access and views of user? in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Good evening all...I have created a module in which there are two kinds of user groups are there..1 is customer 2nd one is admin.. it has only one top menu. i want to hide some left-side menu items when customer logins.So what is the solution to secured erp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an XML file in SECURITY folder of your module.

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="ir_values_my_costume_rule">
    <field name="name">My Rule Name</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_your_model_name"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('field','operator','value'),('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

You must pass **model_** before model name in  like this: **model_**sale_order or **model_**project_task.

Here in **eval** you can either pass **True** or **False** as per you need.

Then you need to use 'groups' attribute like this:

```
<menuitem action="ACTION_ID" id="NEW_MENU_ID" 
       parent="PARENT_MENU_ID" groups="GROUP_XML_ID"/>
```

After making this change in xml file,

> in your **__openerp__.py** file ---> in your **data** tag make an entry for this file.
>
> For example, data:[security/your_module_security.xml]
>
> restart the Openerp server
>
> **Upgrade** your module and check it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want to know about what is domain force?

Comment: Domain means filter. When you want to work on particular record for ex. Here it filters a particular user..which means you don't want to do any desired operation on all the records but only on those records which satisfies given condition......then you can use this DOMAIN to filter out unnecessary records. Hope you got your answer. Thanks.